# Unit Test for Shell and UI in Silverlight Prism

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

I need to add Unit Test Cases for Shell and UI for the project. I searched a lot, but didn't get anything heplful. Can any one provide me the samples for this??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe Jenkins is one of what you want, it can run Shell scripts on Web GUI.